# Command #id to revoke invite link

Tags: api, telegram, telegram-api

I'm trying to revoke telegram super group invite link with script, but can't find any command neither in command line clients (telegram-cli/telethon), nor in current [tl-schema](https://core.telegram.org/#api-methods) to do this.

There is `0xC7560885` to get invite link. There is `MTPchannels_ExportInvite` mentioned in telegram-desktop, executed on 'Revoke invite link' click, but i can't find the definition

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

You can look up [unofficial reference](https://tjhorner.com/tl-schema/#method-channels.exportInvite).

Android [client](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/ui/GroupInviteActivity.java#L198-L239) `generateLink` function may help.